# Create a excel matrix where each row and column sums to exactly 2

Tags: excel, solver

I have a excel sheet with a matrix. The diagonal elements of this matrix are all 1's, the other elements of this matrix will be 0's initially. I want to use the excel solver utility so that each row and column sums exactly to 2. The non diagonal elements which are initialized to 0 should be free to take up any value between 0 and 1 so that the final sum of each row and column should appear as 2. Any help on how to solve this problem in excel will be highly appreciated. The excel matrix is shown below.

[image]

Comment: So all other cells will be 1/n. Or are you searching for multiple random solutions?

Comment: @AxelRichter 1/(n-1)

Comment: @Erwin Kalvelagen: No, since n starts with 0 according the linked screenshot ;-).

Comment: @AxelRichter Got it.

Comment: Any single solution will be good enough.

Comment: So since n is 5 in your screen shot, the solution is 1/n = 1/5 = 0.2 for all other elements of the matrix which are not set to 1.